# Change backgroun on click using xml file

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to change background of ImageView when i click on it , i learned that it could be done by creating XML file and make a selector so i did that but when i execute i see the background has already changed that's my codes :

change.XML file in drawable folder :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#00FF00"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

content_main.xml in Layout folder :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.othma.test2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/str"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgstart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:background="@drawable/change"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //imgV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change.xml file should be like below,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item android:state_pressed="true">
                <color android:color="#00FF00"/>
            </item>
           <item>
                <color android:color="Some-other-color"/>
            </item>
    </selector>
```

Also add the attribute `android:clickable="true"` in the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks the one problem was this attribute Clickable

Comment: when i touch it and drag finger far it returns to normal state that is good but i when i drag finger back to the image i want it to change its background with the same color

Answer (score 0):

In your selector, you only supllied the color for **pressed state** (state_pressed). You need to put the color for **normal state** in there too. More about it in [Color State List documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#00FF00"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="#000000"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: when i touch it , it changes background now i'm still touching it and i want that when i drag finger far it becomes normal and when i drag finger to the image it changes background again ect ..